# How to scrape my own site? (php/wordpress plugin)

Tags: php, wordpress, screen-scraping

I am trying to make a table on my website display images and text based on the data of another hidden table that is easily pasted into the website.

I feel like this should be pretty simple but I do not know where to begin looking. I dont know if this is similar to scraping another site or if there is a wordpress plugin where I can make a certain input display certain things in a table.

Thanks

EDIT - Forget scraping, I just want to display something based on something I paste in that is hidden.

I have a stylized table and a table that with the data that will be pasted in. I want the data in the pasted in table to show in the stylized table, but if the data is, for example "123", I don't want it to display "123" but a certain image instead.

Comment: If the data is in the DB already why not just query for what you need?

Comment: Google  `web scraping with curl`

Comment: @chris85 I guess because I do not know how.

Comment: @RobertRocha 

<?php
    $scraped_page = curl("http://www.example.com");    
    $scraped_data = scrape_between($scraped_page, "<div class="cell 1">", "</div>");
     
    echo $scraped_data; 
?>

Would this scrape the data in a certain cell? But then how would I display something different based on what that scraped data is?

Comment: hi - i would go and try this job with bs4